# How/Why would the scheduler website log attempts to access it's home page?

Tags: multisite, logging

Looking at the log file on our CD server, I noticed that there are loads of warnings getting logged every millisecond for a document not found redirect for the home page of the scheduler website:

> 9376 09:20:17 WARN  Request is redirected to document not found page. Requested url: /, User: sitecore\Anonymous, Website: scheduler

The scheduler is indeed a node of the sites section (this is a multi-site solution), third from the bottom and after all the actual public facing sites but has nothing more than name, domain and enable tracking set to false.

```xml
<site name="scheduler" enableTracking="false" domain="sitecore"/>
```

The only way I can even imagine the site getting accessed is by specifying via query string `sc_site=scheduler` but that still doesn't explain the frequency that it is getting logged.

Comment: Do you have any agents being ran on your CD Server?

Comment: Good question. Not that I am aware of. But I'll check with our infrastructure team.

Answer (score 10):

One thing to be aware of, is that in Sitecore's Site Provider, *order of sites* is **incredibly important**.  If for some reason, your order has become unordered.. and the `scheduler` site shows up in the list BEFORE other site definitions, then Sitecore will land on the `scheduler` site as the Site for the current Context.

Sitecore's Site Provider processes sites using a *Most Specific* to *Least Specific* case.  Because the `scheduler` site has the least amount of requirements, if the sites are out of order, it will chose that site.

This is why `scheduler`, `publisher`, and `system` sites show up **AFTER** the `website` site in a default config.

[image]

### Things To Check

- Check your `ShowConfig.aspx` to see how sites are ordered (if using config patching for Site definition.
- If using any kind of Multi-site manager or dynamic site module, ensure that your site definitions are putting your site before `scheduler`.
- Check to ensure that all site definitions exist. If there isn't a catch all site like `website` that has a empty hostname attribute, then I could also see how a request gets to the `scheduler` site.
- Also check to see if any rogue Scheduler Agents are being processed on the CD. (Likely not, but good to check)

Comment: Great answer, Pete! Can you elaborate a little on what you mean by "the `scheduler` site has the least amount of requirements"? Are you referring to the number of attributes, or something else?

Comment: Yeah sure.. I'll elaborate in the answer, but I gotta go back to work first.:)  Give me a few to get to it.

Comment: Pete - thank you for the thorough answer! I did check site via the `ShowConfig.aspx` and everything is ordered correctly. I did notice that the `website` site node has a `hostName` attribute, so I will try removing so it can be a catch-all to see if it helps. If so I will mark this as the correct answer.